# how convert Hexadecimal to Text in vb.net

Tags: hex

how convert Hexadecimal to Text vb.net

hex:
00530061006D0061002C00200053006F006C006400650020003400380035002C0037003000440041

The result:
Sama, Solde 485,70DA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgCl9.png)

The following site does the conversion, how is that possible in vb.Net?
https://www.hextotext.com/en/convert-hex-to-text